# Restricting values of command line options

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

How do I restrict the values of the argparse options?

In the below code `sau` option should only accept a number of `0` or `1` and `bg` should only allow an integer. How can I implement this?

```
import os
import sys, getopt
import argparse

def main ():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test script')
    parser.add_argument('-sau','--set',action='store',dest='set',help='<Required> Set flag',required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-bg','--base_g',action='store',dest='base_g',help='<Required> Base g',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args() # collect cmd line args
    set = results.set
    base_g = results.base_g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: don't mask the builtin: `set = results.set` (you see the syntax highlighting colour)

Comment: Also, on a sidenote, if arguments are required, they shouldn't be flags but positional arguments.

Comment: check this tutorial http://docs.python.org/howto/argparse

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the [`type=`](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#type) and [`choices=`](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#choices) arguments of [`add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument). To accept only `'0'` and `'1'`, you'd do:

```
parser.add_argument(…, choices={"0", "1"})
```

And to accept only integer numbers, you'd do:

```
parser.add_argument(…, type=int)
```

Note that in `choices`, you have to give the options in the type you specified as the `type` argument. So to check for integers *and* allow only `0` and `1`, you'd do:

```
parser.add_argument(…, type=int, choices={0, 1})
```

Example:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> _ = parser.add_argument("-p", type=int, choices={0, 1})
>>> parser.parse_args(["-p", "0"])
Namespace(p=0)
```